# Import Data from facebook ads to bigquery

Tags: facebook, google-bigquery, ads

I want to send the data from my facebooks ads to bigquery. I could just find one tutorial, from Andrey Osypov, which finally did not worked out for me.

Do someone know any source(s) for a tutorial?

Comment: You can do data transfer from facebook ads to BigQuery using google cloud console following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/third-party-transfer?hl=en_US&_ga=2.183361254.-1110747953.1660829756). Let me know if it's helpful or not?

Comment: The solution you provided go through a third service which I don't want to go. My aim is to access the data directly. Although thank you for the proposition.

Comment: Currently it's not possible to directly export data from Facebook Ads to BigQuery without using third party tools. If you want this feature to be implemented, you can open a new [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) on the issue tracker describing your requirement.

Comment: You are asking for tutorials, that is an off-topic question.